# Unity Launcher integration and quickly run... fail

Tags: unity, application-development, quickly

I'm trying to use the uniy launcher with progress bar.. but it doesn't work..
I just followed the first example on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqGfsgz1Sl4&list=UUWUDCz-Q0m4qK7lkK4CevQA&index=4&feature=plcp and watched the code of the hello-unity ppa ... trying integration in my apps.. and it doesn't work.

What I did:

- added from gi.repository import Unity;
- added self.launcher = Unity.LauncherEntry.get_for_desktop_id ("protoborsa.desktop") in the init code of my window application.
- added launcher.set_property("progress", 0.42) after my application is displayed
- added launcher.set_property("progress_visible", True) after my application is displayed

and nothing happened after quickly run...

I tried to follow this also..
[How do I make the launcher progress bar work with my application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158347/how-do-i-make-the-launcher-progress-bar-work-with-my-application) but it didn't work for me.

many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your code so I can see more of what it's doing?

Comment: I will provide later, cause I don't have the code here with me..

Comment: here is the code of another sample:http://paste.ubuntu.com/1077705/

Comment: @mhall119  I created a new ubuntu-application with the quickly command...for make a test, same result. This is the class called for the main window application http://paste.ubuntu.com/1077705/ the method showMeProgress_click it's a callback to a click on a button on the window. The 2 print statements (progress start and progress end) are showed but nothing happened to the launcher. What am I doing wrong? there is a ustockquotes.desktop.in in the directory of the project..but not ustockquotes.desktop ... I am using quickly and I do quickly run to launch the project. Thanks you

Comment: I don't know why but now, after I've copied the file project.desktop.in (project is the name of the quickly project) inside the project folder in ~/.local/share/applications/ it works.

Comment: @dega1999 Please post your own answer with this information. Then it will be clear to people searching that this was fixed and how, and this question won't appear to still need an answer. (You can accept your own answer 2 days after posting it.)

Comment: @EliahKagan ok! I didn't know... I do :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but now, after I've copied the file `myproject.desktop.in` (`myproject` is the name of the quickly project) inside the project folder in `~/.local/share/applications/myproject.desktop`, it works.